# Join only shows one record

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am trying to join a table but I only get one record in return.

I got 2 tables: ads and `ads_bid`. ads always has `ads_id`. `ads_bid` is only filled with `ads_id` if someone bid on an ad.

What I want is the all the ad information from ads and the highest bid from the table `ads_id`

I tried that with the following:

```
SELECT 
    a.*
FROM 
    ads as a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ab1.ads_id, ab1.bid
    FROM ads_bid as ab1
) as ab
ON
    a.ads_id = ab.ads_id
WHERE 
    a.belong_to_categories = :categories_id
AND
    (a.ads_status = :ads_status1 OR a.ads_status = :ads_status2)
ORDER BY 
    a.ads_id DESC
LIMIT :limit, :perpage
```

You can assume that the limit and the perpage aswell as the ads_status are correct.

This is giving me 1 ad with the highest bid. There are around 10 ads per category, so I was expected to get 10 ads with 9 empty bids and 1 ad with a bid.

What am I doing wrong?

ads table

[image]

ads bid table

[image]

So i want the blue column from the 2nd pic to join the first pic. ads_id 0000000003 isn't in the ads_bid table so i expect the bid value to be empty instead of leaving 0000000003 out of the results at all

Comment: https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: Coulde you provide an sqlfiddle with raw data?

Comment: @Alex - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d031bd/5

Comment: from sqlfiddle provided: you have 4 rows in `ads_bid` table and all of them have `ads_id = 0000000004`. Since you use this field as a key for `INNER JOIN` operation, that means that only `ads_id = 0000000004` will be in result set. And you  have it. So what is wrong with your current result? What is your expected result?

Comment: Well Alex, i expect to have all the data from the ads table and basically 1 extra column "bid" added to that dataset with the highest value from the ads_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still not sure of what is your expected result. It is not clear from your post.

But here is my attempt to start from:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d031bd/10

```
SELECT 
    a.*, ab.bid
FROM 
    ads as a
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT ads_id, MAX(bid) bid
  FROM ads_bid
  GROUP BY ads_id
) as ab
ON 
    a.ads_id = ab.ads_id
WHERE 
    a.belong_to_categories = '0000000014_0000000016_0000000025'
AND
    (a.ads_status = 1 OR a.ads_status = 3)
ORDER BY 
    a.ads_id DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks thats it, i wanted all results as you did with the extra column bid

Answer (score 0):

> expected 10 ads with 9 empty bids and 1 ad with a bid

Am I to understand then that `ads_bid` has only 1 record?  If that's the case then what you're looking for is `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, not `INNER JOIN`.  An `INNER JOIN` will produce results only when both tables have a match for any given record, whereas an `OUTER JOIN` will produce the superset of results and leave the extra fields as `NULL` when no matching record in the joined table is found.

(Specifically a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` will show the superset of records for the "first" table in the join, and `NULL` values when no record is matched in the table being joined.  Other types of `OUTER JOIN`s can be used to show the "full" superset, or the superset of the table being joined, etc.)

Comment: @poNgz0r: Perhaps you can update the question with sample data and expected vs. actual results?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
select a.*, b.max_bid 
from ads a 
left join (
  select b1.ads_id, IFNULL(max(b1.bid),0) as max_bid from ads_bid b1 group by b1.ads_id
) b on a.ads_id=b.ads_id
```

p.s. I haven't tested it :)